# 550 Denied Proftpd User

Tags: permissions, apache2, ftp

When I create a directory from Php Script I have:

```
drwxr-sr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 18:52 folder
```

Here Users:

- User: `www-data`

  ```
  root@101:/mnt/storage_01# groups www-data
  www-data : www-data storage_01
  ```
- User: `storage_01`

  ```
  root@101:/mnt/storage_01# groups storage_01
  storage_01 : storage_01 www-data
  ```

I have added user `storage_01` to `www-data` group, but `550` error continue, user cannot delete files and folders from FTP Access.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

**Try chmod**

Your `www-data` group does not have write permissions on the folder, only user `www-data` does. Run:

```
chmod g+w folder
```

If you have subfolders and files within the folder, run:

```
chmod -R g+w folder
```

Comment: Ran command, but now folder appear this: 
dr----s--t 2 www-data           www-data 4096 May 14 21:57 ixq4mz